# How to separate data inside Redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, koa

I want to use `koa-ratelimit` (rate limiter middleware for Koa, it uses Redis) and `koa-redis` (Redis storage for Koa session middleware) together.

Something like this:

```
import ratelimit from "koa-ratelimit";
import Redis from "ioredis";
import Router from "koa-router";
import session from "koa-generic-session";
import redisStore from "koa-redis";
import Koa from "koa";

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();
const redisClient = new Redis();

router.post(
  "/auth",
  ratelimit({
    db: redisClient,
    duration: 60000,
    errorMessage: "Sometimes You Just Have to Slow Down.",
    id: (ctx) => ctx.ip,
    headers: {
      remaining: "Rate-Limit-Remaining",
      reset: "Rate-Limit-Reset",
      total: "Rate-Limit-Total",
    },
    max: 100,
    disableHeader: false,
  }),
);

app
  .use(session({
    store: redisStore({
      client: redisClient,
    }),
  }))
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

Both libraries require a Redis client.
I want to separate them inside Redis.
I have three ways to do it:

1. **Prefix**. Redis client for Node.js provides ability to prefix all used keys. (https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#rediscreateclient) *Issue:* it looks like a workaround.
2. **Databases**. Redis server provides logical databases. (https://redis.io/commands/select) *Issue:* Redis CLUSTER only supports one logical database.
3. **Separated Redis Instances**. I can run separate instances of Redis on different ports. *Issue:* adds significant administrative overhead.

Which option is better?
Or maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is probably the best option, Redis instance is a very lightweight and starting another shouldn't create too much overhead.

Also, in case you'll want to separate those "databases" in the future or have different cluster deployment it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible) for that.

It allows to create koa middleware with `keyPrefix` option for rate limiting and use the same Redis client `koa-redis`.